# FFT in Cuda, input 4096, wrong results

Tags: cuda, fft

i have implemented an 1d fft in CUDA. Below is the code:

```
// DIT FFT algorithm
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PI 3.141592653

struct complex
{
    float real, imag;
};

void fill(complex *x, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        x[i].real = i;
        x[i].imag = 0;
    }
}

__device__ int bit_reversal(int x, float N)
{
    float log2N = log2f(N);
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < log2N; i++)
    {
        n <<= 1;
        n |= (x & 1);
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return n;
}

__global__ void fft(complex *x, complex *rev_x, int N)
{
    int thread_id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int butterfly_width, step;
    struct complex wn, temp1, temp2;
    float stages = log2f(N);

//bit reversal
int r = bit_reversal(thread_id, N);
rev_x[thread_id] = x[r];
__syncthreads();

//constant expression, used in twiddle factor
const double twoPIdivN = 2 * PI / N;

if (N > 1))
{
    for (int stage = 1; stage <= stages; stage++)
    {
        step = 1 << stage;
        butterfly_width = step >> 1;
        int pos = thread_id / butterfly_width * step;
        //printf("pos=%d ", pos);
        int j = thread_id % butterfly_width;
        int res = pos + j;
        if (res < N)
        {
            //printf("thread: %d, pos: %d, j: %d, res:%d ", thread_id, pos, j, res);
            //Wn = e^(-j*2*PI/N) converted with euler's formula(real and imaginary parts)
            wn.real = cos(twoPIdivN * j * N / step);
            wn.imag = -sin(twoPIdivN * j * N / step);

            temp1.real = rev_x[res].real;
            temp1.imag = rev_x[res].imag;
            temp2.real = rev_x[res + butterfly_width].real * wn.real - rev_x[res + butterfly_width].imag * wn.imag;
            temp2.imag = rev_x[res + butterfly_width].imag * wn.real + rev_x[res + butterfly_width].real * wn.imag;

            rev_x[res].real = temp1.real + temp2.real;
            rev_x[res].imag = temp1.imag + temp2.imag;
            rev_x[res + butterfly_width].real = temp1.real - temp2.real;
            rev_x[res + butterfly_width].imag = temp1.imag - temp2.imag;
            //printf("(%1.2f %1.2fj) ", rev_x[thread_id].real, rev_x[thread_id].imag);
            //printf("(%1.2f %1.2fj) ", rev_x[thread_id + butterfly_width].real, rev_x[thread_id + butterfly_width].imag);
            //printf("(%d %d)", res, res+butterfly_width);
            __syncthreads();
            //printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
}

int main()

{


int N = 4096 // input number of elements

    int threads = 1024;
    int blocks = (N / threads == 0) ? 1 : N / threads;
 
    struct complex *input = (struct complex *)malloc(N * sizeof(struct complex));
    // struct complex *rev_input = (struct complex *)malloc(N * sizeof(struct complex));
    
    fill(input, N);

    struct complex *dev_input;
    struct complex *dev_rev_input;
    size_t size = N * sizeof(struct complex);

    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_input, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_rev_input, size);

    cudaMemcpy(dev_input, input, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 
    fft<<<blocks, threads>>>(dev_input, dev_rev_input, N);


    cudaMemcpy(input, dev_rev_input, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    
    //result fft
    // printf("\nResult of fft: \n");
    // for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    // {
    //     printf(" %d- (%1.2f , %1.2fj)\n", i, input[i].real, input[i].imag);
    //     printf(" %d- (%1.2f , %1.2fj)\n", N - i - 1, input[N - 1 - i].real, input[N - 1 - i].imag);
    // }
    
    free(input);
    cudaFree(dev_input);

return 0;
}
```

With printf in main i take some samples and with MATLAB i verify them.
My input sequence is length of 4096. 
With threads=1024 (my gpu supports 1024threads/block) algorithm works fine.
With threads=512 and fewer results are wrong.
What is the problem. Does anyone have any idea?

**EDIT**
i moved for outside kernel. Code is now:

```
__global__ void fft(complex *x, complex *rev_x, int N, int stage, int butterfly_width, int step){

struct complex wn, temp1, temp2;

//constant expression, used in twiddle factor 
const double twoPIdivN = 2 * PI / N;

int thread_id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

if(stage==1){
    int r = bit_reversal(thread_id, N);
    rev_x[thread_id] = x[r];
    __syncthreads();
}

int pos = thread_id / butterfly_width * step;
int j = thread_id % butterfly_width;
int res = pos + j;

if (res < N)
{
    //Wn = e^(-j*2*PI/N) converted with euler's formula(real and imaginary parts)
    wn.real = cos(twoPIdivN * j * N / step);
    wn.imag = -sin(twoPIdivN * j * N / step);

    temp1.real = rev_x[res].real;
    temp1.imag = rev_x[res].imag;
    temp2.real = rev_x[res + butterfly_width].real * wn.real - rev_x[res + butterfly_width].imag * wn.imag;
    temp2.imag = rev_x[res + butterfly_width].imag * wn.real + rev_x[res + butterfly_width].real * wn.imag;

    rev_x[res].real = temp1.real + temp2.real;
    rev_x[res].imag = temp1.imag + temp2.imag;
    rev_x[res + butterfly_width].real = temp1.real - temp2.real;
    rev_x[res + butterfly_width].imag = temp1.imag - temp2.imag;
        
    __syncthreads();
}     
}

void fft_caller(complex *x, complex *rev_x, int N)
{
    dim3 threads(BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 blocks(GRID_SIZE);
    // int threads = 1024;
    // int blocks=1;
    float stages = log2f(N);
    int butterfly_width, step;

if (N > 1 && is_power_of_two(N))
{
    for (int stage = 1; stage <= stages; stage++)
    {   
        printf("%d ", stage);
        step = 1 << stage;
        butterfly_width = step >> 1;
        fft<<<blocks, threads>>>(x, rev_x, N, stage, butterfly_width, step);
    }
}
```

}

Now algorithm works fine until input length: 16384(2^14). For bigger inputs produces wrong results. What going on?

**EDIT**

I separated one kernel into 3 kernels. Below is code:

```
    __global__ void preproccess(complex *x, complex *rev_x, int N, int stage){
    int thread_id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
        int r = bit_reversal(thread_id, N);
}

    __global__ void compute_temp(complex *rev_x, int N, int stage, int butterfly_width, int step, complex *temp1, complex *temp2){
        struct complex wn;

    int thread_id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    //constant expression, used in twiddle factor 
    const double twoPIdivN = 2 * PI / N;

    
    int pos = thread_id / butterfly_width * step;
    int j = thread_id % butterfly_width;
    int res = pos + j;
    if (res < N)
    {
        //Wn = e^(-j*2*PI/N) converted with euler's formula(real and imaginary parts)
        wn.real = cos(twoPIdivN * j * N / step);
        wn.imag = -sin(twoPIdivN * j * N / step);

        temp1[thread_id].real = rev_x[res].real;
        temp1[thread_id].imag = rev_x[res].imag;
        temp2[thread_id].real = rev_x[res + butterfly_width].real * wn.real - rev_x[res + butterfly_width].imag * wn.imag;
        temp2[thread_id].imag = rev_x[res + butterfly_width].imag * wn.real + rev_x[res + butterfly_width].real * wn.imag;
        
    }
}

__global__ void fft(complex *rev_x, int N, int stage, int butterfly_width, int step, complex *temp1, complex *temp2){
    
    int thread_id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    //constant expression, used in twiddle factor 
    const double twoPIdivN = 2 * PI / N;

    
    int pos = thread_id / butterfly_width * step;
    int j = thread_id % butterfly_width;
    int res = pos + j;
    if (res < N)
    {
        rev_x[res].real = temp1[thread_id].real + temp2[thread_id].real;
        rev_x[res].imag = temp1[thread_id].imag + temp2[thread_id].imag;
        rev_x[res + butterfly_width].real = temp1[thread_id].real - temp2[thread_id].real;
        rev_x[res + butterfly_width].imag = temp1[thread_id].imag - temp2[thread_id].imag;

    }     
}

void fft_caller(complex *x, complex *rev_x, int N)
{
    dim3 threads(BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 blocks(GRID_SIZE);
    // int threads = 1024;
    // int blocks=1;
    float stages = log2f(N);
    int butterfly_width, step;

    struct complex *temp1;
    struct complex *temp2;
    size_t size = N * sizeof(struct complex);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **)&temp1, size));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **)&temp2, size));
    
    if (N > 1 && is_power_of_two(N))
    {
        for (int stage = 1; stage <= stages; stage++)
        {   
            step = 1 << stage;
            butterfly_width = step >> 1;
            if(stage==1)
                preproccess<<<blocks,threads>>>(x, rev_x, N, stage);

            compute_temp<<<blocks, threads>>>(rev_x, N, stage, butterfly_width, step, temp1, temp2);
            fft<<<blocks, threads>>>(rev_x, N, stage, butterfly_width, step, temp1, temp2);
            
            cudaDeviceSynchronize();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You still have `__syncthreads()` calls inside your kernel. They sync only on block level and in your case that is not enough. By putting the for loop outside, you have grid-level synchronization, as one kernel launch is run after the other. You should start a new kernel after the `bit_reversal` in stage 1 and restart the kernel after calculating `temp1` and `temp2` (store it in an array in memory). Just separate the kernel into two (or three including the `bit_reversal`) and call both in the body of your for loop. Otherwise some threads overwrite `rev_x` before others have read it.

Comment: @Sebastian so you mean i break my global function into 2 smaller global functions?

Comment: @i am a litlle cofused. Could you write a pseudocode of your explanation?

Comment: Yes, actually in 3. Look, how `rev_x` is used. In `stage==1` it is accessed with index `thread_id`, then with `res` and `res+butterfly_width`. If `res` and `res+butterfly_width` are in different blocks, you have a race condition. You do not know, if the the other thread has already written the value for this stage before you had the chance to read it. So you have to separate reading and writing.

Comment: So create 3 kernels `fft_preprocess_stage1`, `fft_read`, `fft_write`. `fft_preprocess_stage1` should do the `bit_reversal`-block, `fft_read` should do the reading and calculating of the `temp`-values. `fft_write` should take the temp values and write them into `rev_x`. You need additional memory to store the temp values between kernel launches.

Comment: @Sebastian Right i understodo tha. temp vars, couldnt i have them in fft_caller() decalred? and pass them as arguments in fft_read and fft_write kernels?

Comment: But how would be the right temp value assigned to the right thread_id?

Comment: Just use a memory array large enough to hold all temp values for all threads. You can take use of thread_id for indexing. `complex* temp1array; cudaMalloc(&temp1array, BLOCK_SIZE * GRID_SIZE * sizeof(complex));`

Comment: I think it is reasonably fast for a first solution. You should allocate the array at the start of the program and not in the for loop (allocation functions are typically slow in comparison to calculation).

Comment: Okay i got it. One question. This declaration: int thread_id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x; , has to be in every kernel? or in the first? and pass it as arguement?

Comment: You have to do it in every kernel. Such calculations without memory accesses (additions/multiplication on int and float) are very fast. The arguments are copied identically to all threads. So the thread_id basically is the only way to distinguish between threads. There are some variants possible, how to combine a thread_id or use it.

Comment: @Sebastian, i did what you said, separating kernel into 3. But every result element is 0. I think something is wrong passing temp1, temp2 as arguements. Or indexing of temp2 is fale. Check my edit to see what i mean. Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastian, oh i forgot rev_x[thread_id] = x[r]; in first kernel(preproccess). It worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: There are some small things you could directly optimize: The `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` is unnecessary, as the kernels (belonging to the same stream) will be called sequentially anyway. The `twoPIdivN` variable is `const`, but will be calculated at every launch for each thread. You could just forward it as parameter from the CPU. It also contains `/N` and is multiplied with `*N` again directly afterwards. For sin and cos there is the `sincos` function https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_1gbe0e6a063a8f38850b0323933cf3320b

Comment: You could combine the second and third kernel again in the following way: The `fft`-kernel of the previous stage and the `compute_temp`-kernel of the next stage, with special consideration of the first and last stage. The memory accesses could be faster, if you separate `real` and `imag` into separate arrays especially for the `temp` variables, but also for `x_rev` as there are less memory transactions needed, when accessing elements 4 bytes apart between the threads of an warp. Just to give you some ideas. But you have a working code now and should keep it tidy and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

`__syncthreads()` only synchronizes within a block and not between blocks.

Easiest would be to call your kernel `fft<<<>>>` for each stage separately in a loop instead of having the loop inside the kernel.

```
float stages = log2f(N);
for (int stage = 1; stage <= stages; stage++)
    fft<<<blocks, threads>>>(dev_input, dev_rev_input, N, stage);
```

Please make sure that inside the kernel `fft` the synchronization should not actually happen between calculating the `temp1` and `temp2` values and writing them back (I strongly assume it does) instead of at the end of the stages as your current `__syncthreads()` call would indicate.

In this case, you could process the second half of the previous stage and the first half of the next stage in one kernel launch, and save the intermediate results in a temporary global memory. Special consideration has to be done at the first and last kernel launch, as only one half would have to be executed.

(I assume the implementation is for self-learning or something similar, as there would be lots of performance improvements possible for doing FFT on a GPU architecture, which are well beyond the scope of a question on stack overflow.)

Comment: i want it for a project for my Uni. Thank you for your reply. What do you mean by perf. optimatizations for FFt in GPU arch?

Comment: A library like cufft (written in Cuda) probably will do the FFT more than 100x as fast on the same hardware after the authors at Nvidia put a lot of optimization effort into it, but do not worry.

Comment: please check my edit.

Comment: could i ask you a question? It΄s a bit out of this topic. I have to write how compilation process in a CUDA program goes. At first, i said that host code and device code is partitioned. Host code is compiled with standard c compilers that are invoked by nvcc compiler driver. But for device code, i read about PTX/Cubin objects and JIT compilation. Could you exaplain me in simple words what happens in device code?

Comment: There are virtual and real architectures. First the PTX code for a virtual architecture is compiled, then it is optionally further assembled (ptxas) into a .cubin file (with SASS code) for a real architecture. The ptx and cubin files are put into a fatbinary. The device linker optionally can be run on several fatbinaries. During execution the ptx code can be JIT-assembled into further real architectures. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#cuda-compilation-trajectory

Comment: If you find The Cuda Handbook from Addison Wesley as ebook or on paper there is a description on page 57